# Can a GET POST be implemented in a return jsonify(data) function?

Tags: python, post, flask, get

I have:

server:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/indexGetData', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def loadData():
if (request.method == 'POST'):
   myval = request.form.get('user_ID')
   query = "select * from abc where xyz = :myval"
   cursor.execute(query, myval=myval)
   # convert the result to json
   return jsonify(data)
```

form:

```
<form method="post" action ="/indexGetData">
<input type="text" id="userID" name="user_ID">
<input type="submit" value="Search"
</form>
```

and would like to get values from the user form in the index.html template to pass to the sql query. Please advise... I have been getting Method not allowed error

Comment: Please edit your post with the code of the "user form in the index template" and the full error traceback.

Comment: Have done sir. Please have a look

Comment: Your form doesn't define the 'action' attribute, so it's posting to '/', not to  '/indexGetData'. Also note that if you're using it for search-like / filtering operations, you should be using the GET method, not POST.

Comment: '/indexGetData' is used by a datatable where I'm printing data, in index.html.

Comment: define action in form

Comment: Done :) but still not able to pass the form value

Comment: You are getting method not allowed on submitting the form? How you are submitting? There is no submit button. And the python code has incorrect indentation. And to which url you are submitting the form. There is no `action` attr in the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = "select * from abc where xyz = " + str(myval)
data = db.engine.execute(query)
ret= []
for i in data:
    ret.append(
            {
                "key": i.key
            }
      )
return jsonify(ret)
```

Comment: The issue I'm having is getting the value from the form and passing it to the sql query.

Comment: query = "select * from abc where xyz = " + str(myval) or you can use flask_sql_achemy ORM . ORM will be good to use instead of raw query.